# ObserverField<Drawable> unit test in Android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mockk

How can we write unit test case for view model

If we have ObserverField Drawable
As variable

It is mostly showing
Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract

Or we can't write unit test cases for it?

Thanks